# ArrayOutOfBounds Exception Merge Sort

Tags: java, arrays, exception, mergesort

I'm working on Merge Sort, and an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is being thrown. I've been combing the code looking for the error and cannot find it. The exception stack trace says it is coming from my merge function on line 77 which is `temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];`. Line 102 is `merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, list);` and line 93 is `mergeSortRoutine(firstHalf);`. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Below are the two functions:

```
//this function will merge two arrays
private static void merge(Integer[] list1, Integer[] list2, Integer[] temp){
    int current1 = 0; //current index in list1
    int current2 = 0; //current index in list2
    int current3 = 0; //current index in temp

    while((current1 < list1.length) && (current2 < list2.length)){

        if(list1[current1].intValue() < list2[current2].intValue()){
            temp[current3++] = list1[current1++];
        }
        else{
            temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
        }
    }

    while(current1 < list1.length){
        temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
    }

    while(current2 < list2.length) {
        temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
    }
}

//merge sort function
private static void mergeSortRoutine(Integer[] list){

    if(list.length > 1){

        //merge sort the first half
        Integer[] firstHalf = new Integer[(list.length)/2];
        System.arraycopy(list, 0, firstHalf, 0, (list.length)/2);
        mergeSortRoutine(firstHalf);

        //merge sort the second half
        int secondHalfLength = list.length - ((list.length)/2);
        Integer[] secondHalf = new Integer[secondHalfLength];
        System.arraycopy(list, (list.length)/2, secondHalf, 0, secondHalfLength);
        mergeSortRoutine(secondHalf);

        //merge firstHalf with secondHalf into list
        merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, list);
    }
}
```

Below is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Merge.merge(Merge.java:77)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:102)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.mergeSortRoutine(Merge.java:93)
at Merge.main(Merge.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: you are checking for `current2 < list2.length` in your `loop` but then you go and set it to a higher value `list2[current2++]`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Awesome! Thank you for the extra set of eyes. Got it working! Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Scary Wombat says, in your final `while` loop you're checking current2 and then incrementing it.

In addition to that, you're incrementing `current2` in your second-to-last `while` loop, `while(current1 < list1.length)`. I think you probably intended that statement to be `temp[current3++] = list1[current1++]`.

Comment: Awesome! thank you for the extra set of eyes! I got it working. Thanks again.